# R - DataFrame from List without unwrapping some columns

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have some data parsed from json that I stored in a list named `json`.

Every entry is also a list, `json[[i]]`, made of two sublists, `json[[i]][[1]]` and `json[i]][[2]]`.

Now, I would like to create a dataframe from this data, by unrolling `json[[i]][[1]]` but not `json[[i]][[2]]`. The columns of this dataframe would be as follows:

```
json[[i]][[1]][[1]]  json[[i]][[1]][[2]] ...  json[[i]][[1]][[n]]  json[[i]][[2]]
```

---

**Example:**

```
json <- list(list(list(1,2), list(3,4)), list(list(5,6), list(7,8)))
```

I would like the following datafame:

```
   X1 X2        X3
1   1  2  list(3,4)
2   5  6  list(7,8)
```

---

I tried the following method, but it seems to unwrap the second list as well:

```
columns <- lapply(json, function(y) {
    list(c(y[[1]][[1]],
           y[[1]][[2]], 
           list(y[[2]])))
})
data.frame(matrix(columns))
```

Output:

```
  matrix.columns.
1      1, 2, 3, 4
2      5, 6, 7, 8
```

---

**How could I create this dataframe correctly?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it easy to map and join the data.frames, we can use `purrr:map_dfr()` here. How about

```
purrr::map_dfr(json, function(x) {
  d <- data.frame(
    X1 = x[[1]][[1]],
    X2 = x[[1]][[2]]
  )
  d$X3 <- x[2]
  d
})
```